# why dat[] <- lapply(dat, as.factor) gives dataframe in R

Tags: r, lapply

I can understand that lapply gives a list and that you can unlist it but if you want to apply it to only a few columns in a data frame that would be a problem.

can someone explain to me why df[]<- lapply provides a data frame?

Thank you!

Comment: By using the `[]`, it is preserving the structure of the data at the lhs of `<-`,  It wouldn't be a problem if you subset a few columns, just index iit. i.e. `dat[1:3] <- lapply(dat[1:3], as.factor)` converts the first 3 columns to `factor`

Comment: But why dat[,1:3] <-  lapply(dat[,1:3], as.factor) does work then?

Comment: The indexing is `rowindex, colindex`  If you don't speciy the `,` it will automatically detect it as column index for data.frame.  the `dat[, 1:3]` also works